# How do I fix "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property..."

Tags: c#, xna

I'm trying to write some code that displays my player's X value in text.
It tells me that the `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.SpriteBatch.DrawString` line needs an object reference. Any ideas? Here is my code:

```
public void Effects(Player player)
{
    string compassString = "";
    int playerY = (int) (((player.position.X + player.width) * 2f) / 16f);
    if (playerY > 0)
    {
        compassString = "Distance: " + playerY + " feet left";
        if (playerY == 1)
        {
        compassString = "Distance: " + playerY + " foot left";
        }
    }
    else if (playerY < 0)
    {
        playerY *= -1;
        compassString = "Distance: " + playerY + " feet right";
        if (playerY == 1)
        {
            compassString = "Distance: " + playerY + " foot right";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        compassString = "Distance: Level";
    }
    Color black;
    black.R = (byte)((0xff + black.R) / 2);
    black.G = (byte)((0xff + black.R) / 2);
    black.B = (byte)((0xff + black.R) / 2);
    Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.SpriteBatch.DrawString(Main.fontMouseText, compassString, new Vector2((float) (0x16), (float) ((0x4a + (0x16)) + 0x30)), black, 0f, new Vector2(), (float) 1f, SpriteEffects.None, 0f);

}
```

Comment: You need to call DrawString on an instance of SpriteBatch.

Comment: Like this?: spriteBatch = new Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display the coordinates as string in XNA you have to:

1. Define a new `SpriteFont` in your application.
2. In your `Game.Draw()` method (and not just somewhere in your code!) use the default `spriteBatch` instance to draw the coordinates using the just defined `SprinteFont`.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb447673.aspx) is a good tutorial on these steps from MSDN webpage.

Here is the quote from above linked page:

```
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime) // <- do it here, not somewhere else!
{
    GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

    spriteBatch.Begin(); // <-- before you start to draw

    spriteBatch.DrawString(Font1, output, FontPos, Color.LightGreen,
        0, FontOrigin, 1.0f, SpriteEffects.None, 0.5f);

    spriteBatch.End(); // <-- after you draw
    base.Draw(gameTime);
}
```

Comment: I've modified my code, and it compiles. It refuses to draw them though. What I have now is [this](http://pastebin.com/msMpMdy9)

Comment: Did you read the tutorial? You are doing it wrong way. I added an extended example of code how to do it -- but, please, read the tutorial!

Answer (score 0):

You get that error because SpriteBatch is not a static class. It must be instantiated just like int i = 0; You can not do int.i = 0;

Go to game1.cs. Find the "SpriteBatch spriteBatch" declaration. Either make this one a public static or make another global class (or singleton) that has a public reference to this variable.
The in game1.cs in Draw method you call

```
spriteBatch.Begin();
yourClass.Draw();
spriteBatch.End();
```

Then in YourClass.Draw() put:

```
<yourGlobalClass>.SpriteBatch.DrawString(..);
```

So after the spitebatch is assigned to in game1.cs you can put a line:

```
<yourGlobalClass>.SpriteBatch = spritebatch;
```